# Locally Lipschitz? Globally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions

Does this function $$f(x,y) = -\frac{2xy}{(\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{|y|}+1+x^2)} $$
Satisfy the local Lipshitz condition 
$$|f(x,y_2)-f(x,y_1)| \leq M|y_2-y_1| $$
for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

I have no idea how to approach this. If I come up with something I will post my attempt.

Comment: Observe that you just need a bound on $\partial f/\partial y$, by the mean value theorem (your function is defined everywhere).

Comment: do you mind elaborating? I found $f_y = -\frac{2x(\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{|y|}+1+x^2)}{(\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{|y|}+1+x^2)^2} $ but I dont know how use the mean value theorem to find a bound on it.

Comment: Observe that you have a bound on any bounded set (since your function is continuous, say), so local Lipschitzness is obvious. You only need to control what happens at infinity, for large $x$ and/or $y$. That depends on the leading powers at infinity.

Comment: You are right, but the derivative  is not bounded there . If it were bounded, it would be Lipschitz by the mean value theorem.

Comment: okay i will ponder on this for a bit and get back to you :) Thank you

Comment: understood, MVT matters when looking at some region say a rectangle allowing us to put some bound M for an arbitrary rectangle allowing us to focus on what happens at infinity. Because at infinity the derivative goes to 0 we can say that our M can just be the maximum value of the magnitude of the derivative (whatever that may be). Does that imply that is f globally Lipschitz as well then?

Comment: Yes, it does. All you need is $f_y$ to be bounded on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and for that it is enough to prove that $f_y\to 0$ as $x^2+y^2\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if $x\ne 0,$ then $f_y(x,0)$ does not exist because of the pesky term $\sqrt {|y|}.$ Note that $f$ is odd in $y.$ A differentiable odd function $g$ on $\mathbb R$ always satisfies $g'(0)=0.$ But you can see from your own formula for $f_y$ away from the $x$-axis that $\lim_{y\to 0^+} f_y(x,y)$ is nonzero if $x$ is nonzero. Therefore $f_y(x,0)$ does not exist if $x$ is nonzero.

That's not a problem however. After all, on $\mathbb R$ the function $|t|$ is Lipschitz even though the derivative doesn't exist at $0.$ We have the same general phenomenon here.